# ZPL QR code not printing what is in the string

Tags: qr-code, zebra-printers, zpl

I've got the following ZPL code which prints a QR code with fielddata X50X-8091X-11111.

```
^XA^PON^FWN^FO30,10^BQN,2,6^FDx50x-8091x-12345^FS^XZ
```

But what the scanner scans from the QR code is this: 0X8091X11111. So the first X50 is not printed.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ZPL manual has a very detailed explanation of the data switches for QR codes: [^BQ Command](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#page=104)
Edit: Sorry @Veve, the explination is VERY long.   Here is the simplified explination: [image]

Comment: You should include the relevant part in your answer instead of this "link only answer", in case the link destination disapears.

Comment: Thanks! I thought everything after ^FD was just treated as text

Answer (score 3):

The chars immediately following `^FD` are switches (as defined [here](http://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/BQ_Command.pdf))

So you can use something like this;

```
^XA^FO100,100^BQN,2,4^FD   x50x-8091x-12345^FS^XZ
```

or this;

```
^XA^FO100,100^BQN,2,4^FDHM,A x50x-8091x-12345^FS^XZ
```